# How to set up transformOrigin in Polymer's scale-up-animation?

Tags: polymer

I am using Polymer 1.6.0 and I have the following code with a FAB that toggles a paper-dialog:

```
<template>
    <paper-fab icon="icons:more-horiz" on-tap="toggleDialog"></paper-fab>

    <paper-dialog id="myDialog"
                  entry-animation="scale-up-animation"
                  exit-animation="scale-down-animation">
        ...
    </paper-dialog>
</template>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'my-component',
        toggleDialog: function (e) {
              var x = e.detail.x;
              var y = e.detail.y;
              // Set the entry animation initial coordinates to (x, y)
              // Set the exit animation final coordinates to (x, y)
              this.$.myDialog.toggle();
        }
    });
</script>
```

The dialog scales up from the center of the screen and back down to the same point.

I would like the dialog to scale up from the point where the user clicked the FAB, as well as to scale back down to that point.

My question is: How do I configure the entry and exit animations this way in the code above, if possible?